# Is it possible to use self-signed SMIME certs with Mutt?

Tags: macos, mutt, smime

I'm trying to use a self-signed SMIME key that my company has issued me with Mutt. However, when I try to import it with `smime_keys` I get the following.

```
Couldn't identify root certificate!
No root and no intermediate certificates. Can't continue. at /usr/bin/smime_keys line 708.
```

I'm using Mutt on OSX recently installed using Homebrew. Does anyone know a way to force `smime_keys` to accept my self-signed certificate? Can I add the signing certificate my company uses to some authoritative Root CA file somewhere?

```
##########
# UPDATE #
##########
```

OK, so I was able to get `smime_keys` to accept my self-signed certificate by first adding my company's root CA via `smime_keys add_root root-ca.cer`. Now, however, when I try to decrypt an encrypted email to me Mutt asks me for my encryption certificate's password and once I enter it I get a message saying `Could not copy message`. When I try to send a signed or encrypted email from Mutt, after entering in my certificate's password I get a message saying `Can't open OpenSSL subprocess!: No such file or directory (errno = 2)`.

Some additional info - when I run Mutt in debug mode `mutt -d 3` and try to decrypt an encrypted email to me, I see the following in `.muttdebug0`.

```
Failed on attachment of type application/pkcs7-mime.
Bailing on attachment of type application/pkcs7-mime.
Could not copy message
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I was able to figure out what the heck I was doing wrong here. It comes down to me not having sourced the smime.rc file such that Mutt knew what OpenSSL commands to use when trying to sign/verify and encrypt/decrypt messages.

As an aside, just in case this is useful to anyone, I also figured out how to ensure I can read encrypted emails that I've sent to others when I look at them in my sent folder.

In smime.rc, update the `smime_encrypt_command` to tack your public encryption certificate onto the end of the openssl command. For example:

```
set smime_encrypt_command="openssl smime -encrypt -%a -outform DER -in %f %c ~/.smime/certificates/123456789.0"
```

Where certificate 123456789.0 is your public certificate for S/MIME encryption. Just for completion, `%a` is the variable for which method of encryption to use, `%f` is the variable for the email text being encrypted, and `%c` is the variable for the recipient(s) of the email.

Comment: Specifically, `%f` is the path to a text file containing the plaintext, and `%c` is the path to the recipients' certificates